# How to fix dbcontext concurrency problem with this code

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

The code below was originally written for Entity Framework 6 in a .Net Framework 4.7.2 MVC environment.  We've recently moved our business logic, domain objects and data layers to .NetStandard 2 with Entity Framework Core 3.1 for the data layer until we can get all of our sites updated to .NET 5 at which point we'll update everything else to .NET 5 and the latest Entity Framework.

We recently updated some of our sites to .NET 5 but the underlying data layer hasn't changed.  Before this update, we were not having any issues.  Now since updating the web site to .NET 5, the data layer will sporadically throw this error:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdaFHoncurrencyException(Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagation(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
> at FH.Data.Models.EntityFramework.DataContext.FHDbContext.SaveChanges() in D:\Code\cntr\src\FH.Data.Models\Partials\DataContext\FHDbContext.cs:line 73
> at FH.Data.Access.Repositories.Time.TimesheetRepository.SaveTimePunches(List`1 timePunches) in D:\Code\cntr\src\FH.Data.Access\Repositories\Time\TimesheetRepository.cs:line 2096   at FH.BusinessLogic.Core.Timesheet.TimesheetController.SaveTimePunches(List`1 timePunches) in D:\Code\cntr\src\FHBllStandard\Timesheet\TimesheetController.cs:line 892
> at FH.Employees.Controllers.TimesheetController.SavePunches(List`1 timepunches) in D:\Code\cntr\src\FH.Employees\Controllers\TimesheetController.cs:line 139
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()

Here's the code and it throws the error on the `SaveChanges` line.  Any idea why updating the website would cause this and what can be done to fix it?

```
var workDates = timePunches.Select(x => x.WorkDate.Date)
                           .Distinct().ToList();
var jobId = timePunches.First().JobId;

var punches = _context.TimePunches
                      .Where(y => workDates.Contains(y.WorkDate.Date) && y.JobId == jobId)
                      .ToList();

if (punches.Any())
{
    _context.TimePunches.RemoveRange(punches);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: FYI .NET 5 reached end of support [back in 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-5-end-of-support-update/). You probably want to migrate beyond that to [currently supported versions](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) such as .NET 6 (the current "LTS") or .NET 7.

Comment: Is your dbcontext shared/static?

Comment: You say "sporadic"; is it possible this is just a race condition with multiple users and another user has just deleted that row? If so, it’s just an expected condition your code has to deal with.

Comment: The context is injected by Lamar.  For being a race condition, I wouldn't think so.  I can pretty much guarantee this would be a single user.  This method is called when they change the time on a time input field.  That change fires some javascript that calls a controller that calls this method.  When the change happens it looks to see if it's already saving a change and pauses for 2.5 seconds to try and avoid this.  I am just having a tough time figuring out why it's been working for years and just now is having problems.